# Converting complex SOAP requests to REST URIs

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I am trying to create a REST web service which provides the exact same functionality as an existing SOAP based web service. Some soap requests can be quite complex and I am having trouble figuring out how these could be mapped to URIs. For example the following SOAP method body represents a search:

```
    <HLRequest>
        <HLSearch correlId=”1”>
        <criteria numHLs="10" Level="AND" matchAll="true" exactHitCount="true" suppTemp="true" suppHLOnly="true" chainHLOnly="true" startDate="2011-01-01T00:00:00" endDate="2011-01-07T23:59:59">>
            <symbols>
                <symbol>CSCO</symbol>
                <symbol>IBM</symbol>
                <symbol>MSFT</symbol>
            </symbols>
        </criteria>
        </HLSearch>
        <HLSearch correlId=”2”>
        <criteria numHLs="10">
            <symbols>
                <symbol>GOOG</symbol>
            </symbols>
        </criteria>

         </HLSearch>
    </HLRequest>
```

So I need to construct a method which handles URIs with an indefinite number of repeating query parameters and I'm not sure how/if this can be done within the REST paradigm.

Thanks in advance,
Ned

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're too hung up on a design pattern. There are things that REST is good for, and things that it's not good for, and you've just found one of the latter. You could come up with some scheme to map this data to a URI, but why would you want to? What problem would that solve? For this data, XML is probably the best way to represent it, so why not just post the XML?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I completely agree with this but my costumer wants to move away from XML. I will have to come up with another approach

Comment: Explain to them that in this case, moving away from XML would create more problems than it solves. If they don't go for that, do what bmargulies suggested and use JSON instead. I actually think that in most use cases JSON is a better choice than XML - but I was thinking that since you're already getting XML in the one end, you might as well use it on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to map them all to URIs? A better approach for complex data is to make some json and post that. Apache CXF JAX-RS support can them automatically map that to bean classes.

Comment: No I guess I don't really need to, was just looking into it. I will probably go with the posting json approach